# Cocoa NSView changing autosizing properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Using interface builder you can select the corners an object should stick to when resizing. How can you do this programatically?

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: Please note that Apple introduced an [AutoLayout framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/UserExperience/RNAutomaticLayout/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010631) for Lion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See the [setAutoresizingMask:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setAutoresizingMask:) method of NSView and the associated [resizing masks](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Resizing_masks).

Comment: Here is a working link to the [resizing masks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview.autoresizingmask)

Answer (score 30):

I find that the `autoresizingBit` masks are horribly named, so I use a category on NSView to make things a little more explicit:

```
// MyNSViewCategory.h:
@interface NSView (myCustomMethods)

- (void)fixLeftEdge:(BOOL)fixed;
- (void)fixRightEdge:(BOOL)fixed;
- (void)fixTopEdge:(BOOL)fixed;
- (void)fixBottomEdge:(BOOL)fixed;
- (void)fixWidth:(BOOL)fixed;
- (void)fixHeight:(BOOL)fixed;

@end
```

```
// MyNSViewCategory.m:
@implementation NSView (myCustomMethods)

- (void)setAutoresizingBit:(unsigned int)bitMask toValue:(BOOL)set
{
    if (set)
    { [self setAutoresizingMask:([self autoresizingMask] | bitMask)]; }
    else
    { [self setAutoresizingMask:([self autoresizingMask] & ~bitMask)]; }
}

- (void)fixLeftEdge:(BOOL)fixed
{ [self setAutoresizingBit:NSViewMinXMargin toValue:!fixed]; }

- (void)fixRightEdge:(BOOL)fixed
{ [self setAutoresizingBit:NSViewMaxXMargin toValue:!fixed]; }

- (void)fixTopEdge:(BOOL)fixed
{ [self setAutoresizingBit:NSViewMinYMargin toValue:!fixed]; }

- (void)fixBottomEdge:(BOOL)fixed
{ [self setAutoresizingBit:NSViewMaxYMargin toValue:!fixed]; }

- (void)fixWidth:(BOOL)fixed
{ [self setAutoresizingBit:NSViewWidthSizable toValue:!fixed]; }

- (void)fixHeight:(BOOL)fixed
{ [self setAutoresizingBit:NSViewHeightSizable toValue:!fixed]; }

@end
```

Which can then be used as follows:

```
[someView fixLeftEdge:YES];
[someView fixTopEdge:YES];
[someView fixWidth:NO];
```

Comment: Actually, yes. I've been working on a custom UI for a touch screen interface, and Interface Builder is simply not the right tool for that job. I've been doing everything in code, and I haven't looked back.

Comment: @Karolis: Glad to hear it. Thank you for taking the time to leave a note.

Comment: So you mean it is possible to know what you're doing when you tell a view what to do when it's resized? If there's ever a Nobel Peace Prize for coding, you have my vote.

Comment: Ah, helps my intense dislike for autoresizing masks!  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 7):

Each view has the mask of flags, controlled by setting a the autoresizingMask property with the OR of the behaviors you want from the [resizing masks](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview%5FClass/Reference/NSView.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/constant%5Fgroup/Resizing%5Fmasks).  In addition, the superview needs to be configured to [resize its subviews](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview%5FClass/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setAutoresizesSubviews:).

Finally, in addition to the basic mask-defined resizing options, you can fully control the layout of subviews by implementing [-resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview%5FClass/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:)

Answer (score 3):

@e.James answer gave me an idea to simply create a new enum with more familiar naming:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSViewAutoresizing) {
    NSViewAutoresizingNone                 = NSViewNotSizable,
    NSViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = NSViewMinXMargin,
    NSViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = NSViewWidthSizable,
    NSViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = NSViewMaxXMargin,
    NSViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = NSViewMaxYMargin,
    NSViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = NSViewHeightSizable,
    NSViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = NSViewMinYMargin
};
```

Also, from my research, I discovered that @James.s has a **serious bug in the NSView additions.** The coordinate system in Cocoa has a flipped y-axis in terms of iOS coordinates system. Hence, in order to fix the bottom and top margin, you should write:

```
- (void)fixTopEdge:(BOOL)fixed
{ [self setAutoresizingBit:NSViewMaxYMargin toValue:!fixed]; }

- (void)fixBottomEdge:(BOOL)fixed
{ [self setAutoresizingBit:NSViewMinYMargin toValue:!fixed]; }
```

From the cocoa docs:

> NSViewMinYMargin
>
> ```
> The bottom margin between the receiver and its superview is flexible.
> Available in OS X v10.0 and later.
> ```

Comment: +1 for the hybrid approach! I've never had problems with that code, but perhaps it is a difference between OSX and iOS? Now you have me curious...