# how to support rotate in the textbox created by code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I created a text box by code in Xcode, by giving

```
if (isLandScape) {
    textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(800, 10, 200, 30)];
}
else {
    textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(550, 10, 200, 30)];
}
```

but when rotated, two box are created, I dont want this, what is the treatment for my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look at autoresizingMask property.
2. In what method are you creating this view?

Comment: @denish i tried to follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843683/cocoa-nsview-changing-autosizing-properties but xcode doesnot recognise the NSView, i think that is not for IOS, I am new to autoresizingMask and I am calling this method from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method.

Comment: in your case authoresizingMask should be  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin hence you are adjusting you x of frame. So in viewDidLoad:
1. Choose appropriate frame for current orientation
2. Create UItextField
3. Set autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin

Now all rotation frame adjustments will be made automatically